# Unable to create support case

Tags: case, cloudant

Initially, I had created a case to report a problem with credentials assignment to **Cloudant**. But, after a few iterations with support, I am no longer able to view my own case via the link I get in the support e-mail.
I only get a message `You do not have the right permissions to view cases`.

So, I try to open a new case - but then I get `You do not have the right permissions to open cases` and a description telling me what to do.
Following the steps (Creating an access group for working with cases), I'm able to follow the first steps (From the menu bar, go to Manage > Access (IAM), select Access groups, and click Create), but at the Access Groups page, there is no Create button or any way to create a new access group. 
So, I'm not even able to ask for support any more...

Answer (score 0):

You can always open support cases via email to support@cloudant.com - if you provide your Cloudant account name (the one that ends with -bluemix) it’s easier for support to locate you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will send an email ;-)  I don't have a -bluemix account name, as I am using my IBM intranet ID to work with IBMCloud...

Answer (score 0):

You still have a -bluemix account - look at the URL when opening the Cloudant dashboard. Here’s an instance I just created using my internal IBM creds...

https://5217efab-4dcf-4ea0-a1c7-a0ea017a8ccd-bluemix.cloudant.com

Comment: Might be, but the original Case I had opened was related to the fact that I could not log into the Cloudant dashboard...If I try to open the Cloudant instance, I now get an error and the following https string:

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/services/cloudantnosqldb/29317c7b-5abd-494c-b089-4e9ad5f32ff4?env_id=eu-gb&ace_config=%7B%22region%22%3A%22eu-gb%22%2C%22crn%22%3A%22crn%3Av1%3Abluemix%3Apublic%3Acloudantnosqldb%3Aeu-gb%3As%2F01def16e-c879-4a14-b93f-8d83c08fdf63%3A29317c7b-5abd-494c-b089-4e9ad5f32ff4%3Acf-service-instance%3A%22%2C%22resource_id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22orgGuid%22%3A%2211f2fc61-f459-4744-bcd7-020887edce90%22%2C%22spaceGuid%22%3A%2201def16e-c879-4a14-b93f-8d83c08fdf63%22%2C%22redirect%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.ibm.com%2Fresources%22%2C%22bluemixUIVersion%22%3A%22v6%22%7D